# How to use component A functionalities in component B where both are independent?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular11

I have component A with all functionalities and same needs to be used in component B. Since huge code is written in componentA.ts but not in service so in this case how can make use component A logic without using service where both are independent components.

I saw many post in stack overflow but could not find proper solution.

Comment: Move the functionality you want to share to a different class, and extend that class in components A and B.

Comment: You could use a static class, like a shared class.

Comment: What is the reason this code is not in a service?

Comment: service is used only for api integration part rest all functionalities are in component class.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Any reference how to achieve with shared module ?

Comment: "service is used only for api integration part" Again, why? Nothing stops you from share other functions by service too. Don't make your components too big.

Comment: You don't need to put that class in a module, it's just a class that get exported (IE: `export class MyClass { foo(); }`) and then _extended_ in a component: `export class MyComponent extends MyClass`. Then you can finally use - in the component's scope - the extended class method. `this.foo();`. Be aware that you need to call `super()` in your component's contructor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few approaches to achieve your goal:

1. **Helper.** If it's some complicated logic you can move it into shared helper class (something like 'shared/***.helper.ts)
2. **Inheritance.** You can create parent component with all common logic and inherit it with 'extends' functionality.
   (You can read more about it here: https://www.bitovi.com/blog/4-reasons-to-fall-in-love-with-angular-component-inheritance)
   I personally don't think that this is the best practice for frontend, but in some particular cases it might be reasonable.
3. **Service.** You said that you don't want to use service for that, but it's actually  a valid architectural solution to use services not only for API interactions.
4. **Code duplication.** If we are talking about some small functions which describe simple elements behaviour - it's okay to have small pieces of code duplication in different components.